# Giving a PDF a specific permalink in Jekyll

Tags: html, url, pdf, jekyll

I am looking for a way to ensure that upon build a PDF will end up in a specific directory. I am using the [jekyll-pages-directory](https://github.com/bbakersmith/jekyll-pages-directory) plugin to create the structure of this site. Not looking to embed the PDF in a page, not trying to link to it from my assets folder. Need it to have a URL of that places it within a specific path without redirects.

When I place the PDF into the directory inside of the `pages` folder I get errors from Jekyll about it not being a valid byte sequence. I assume that this means Jekyll doesn't know how to handle the file type. The Error is as follows:

```
Error reading file /Users/path/to/site/_pages/path/to/my.pdf: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 
  Liquid Exception: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 in path/to/my.pdf
jekyll 2.5.3 | Error:  invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
```

So in short how can I make Jekyll place my PDF into the correct directory in `_site` upon build so that I can control what its url would be?

Comment: What is jekyll-pages plugin ?

Comment: Simply dropping a pdf file into the `pages` folder doesn't throw any errors for me.  Are you trying to modify the pdf in some way during the build (e.g., are you adding front matter to the file)?

Comment: David Jacquel: Sorry I mistakenly called it that. It is actually jekyll-pages-directory. I'll edit that into my question, with a link to its readme. It makes creating static pages outside of posts a bit easier. @lando : I am not adding front matter to the file. Just dropping the .pdf into the sub dir so that the path would be something like: _pages/products/instructions.pdf. I will add the exact error momentarily.